# Is overriding controllers in Prestashop not being broken after CMS upgrade

Tags: module, prestashop, overriding, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

Well, I think the title is containing the purpose of my question.

Prestashop documentation is not, in my opinion, clear about updates and their effects. I find no sentence in the documentation indicating that I can always override front controllers without caring my changes are deleted after update to newer versions.

I sometimes understand that the best way to work using Prestashop as a developper is to create modules (not adding or removing from /override/controllers/front/).

Please to explain to me please I am a newbie in Prestashop.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the overrides are for. When you upgrade the overrides stay in place and keep the functionality. Also the template directory has a modules directory and a css/modules directory. They are for overrides to modules. You can override the templates and the css files in those directories and when you upgrade modules they will not be affected.

One thing to watch about controller overrides is that when you upgrade major versions the override might not be compatible with the changes made to the new controllers.

Comment: I upvoted to first thank you for the answer. I will be here accepting after understanding it. Thanks again.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. I just want to ask you another question please: What do you think about creating my own module that will override existing behaviours? Is it better than overriding directly in the override directory?

Comment: I would totally do it as a module, that is how most people do it. The reason being the upgrade can disable and re-enable the module. Plus a shop owner can as well if there is a problem with it.